# Inheritance in function of template argument value

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to have class derived from an other depending on the value of an template argument ?

Something like that :

```
template<std::uint8_t nbr>
class A :
    public B
{}

template<std::uint8_t nbr>
class A
{}
```

If nbr is more than 1, class A derives from class B.
And if nbr = 0, class A isn't derived from class B.

If yes, how can we do it. I check about the type_traits but I don't find.

Answer (score 6):

You might use specialization for that:

```
template<std::uint8_t nbr>
class A : public B
{};

template<>
class A<0>
{};
```

`std::conditional` might also help

```
struct Empty{};

template<std::uint8_t nbr>
class A : public std::conditional_t<nbr == 0, Empty, B>
{};
```

Comment: empty base class optimization is not mandatory, is it? The two arent really equivalent? Just curiosity.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: From [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), since C++11, EBO is mandatory for [StandardLayoutType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) (which A is actually (in that simplified example)).